# paintComponent() is being invoked 200 times

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, paintcomponent, repaint

I am having an odd issue when using paintComponent() and repaint(). 
As you see below, I have a `paintComponent()` class as an inner class as the main JPanel of my GUI.

```
    // add another panel to centerInner
    tableBottom = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (!paintImages.isEmpty()) {
                for (PaintImages temp : paintImages) {
                    g.drawImage(temp.getImage(), temp.getX(), temp.getY(), this);
                }
            }
            if (!extraCards.isEmpty()) {
                for (PaintImages temp1 : extraCards) {
                    g.drawImage(temp1.getImage(), temp1.getX(), temp1.getY(), this);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

This is a black jack game with 4 players a dealer.

`repaint()` is called by 4 functions:

The constructor for the initial draw. 
An update method that creates an `ArrayList` of objects to print for the initial deal.
An another update method that creates an `ArrayList` for each card drawn. 
And the reset which clears all `ArrayLists` and repaints the new initial deal.

I won't go into the backend, but every one of those four methods only run the desired number of times. just once for every time its called.

My problem is that when `paintComponent` is invoked by `repaint()`, `paintComponent()` runs almost 200 times, not including the `for` loops that run around 10 times a piece on average per game.

My question is:

1) Is this common behavior for a `paintComponent` method? Does paintComponent call itself repeatedly over and over again until all painting necessary has been completed?

OR

2) Does this have to do with the JPanel `tableBottom`? at this point nothing is actually being added to the JPanel because it is top most JPanel. But maybe `paintComponent` is ran repeatedly for every JPanel, JFrame, ContentPane, Label, etc.,

OR

3) Did I do something wrong in my code below? Again through testing using increments and print statements I found the update methods are called the appropriate amount of times and doing their jobs correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code looks okay; the problem might be somewhere else. AFAIK paintComponent is called once per component, so it's not incremental. Maybe use the debugger in your IDE to see the call stack? There might be a component misbehaving, triggering a repaint event from within a paint method.

Comment: paintComponent() will be called whenever your tableBottom is resized or whenever it gets an exposure (if there is no backings store), or whenever its parent resets its position. How often is repaint being called? (Just override it and have it call super.repaint() ) ?

Comment: @FredK it is called once for the initial draw, once per card drawn after that. I removed the other 2 that I had before. What will `super.repaint()` doand where would I put it? At the moment because of `paintComponent` being a inner class I call repaint like `tableBottom.paintComponent()`

Answer (score 3):

> being a inner class I call repaint like tableBottom.paintComponent()

Never invoke the paintComponent() method directly. To repaint the panel you do:

```
tableBottom.repaint();
```

The request will be passed to the RepaintManager which will then combine repaint() requests for all components and then paint the components as necessary. This will make painting more efficient.

```
g.drawImage(temp1.getImage(), temp1.getX(), temp1.getY(), this);
```

The "this" means that images can be repainted as they are being read. That is sometimes the painting method is invoked before the image I/O has completed. So in this case when the I/O is finished another paint request will be made so the image is painted completely. If you are reading the images at the start of you class and storing them in some data structure then you can probably just use "null" instead of "this".

> Did I do something wrong in my code below?

The code provide looks reasonable, but we can't see the context of how/when you invoke the painting code. I already mentioned one problem.

Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.